# How to remove a specific container when it has no unique ID

Tags: javascript, html

I've implemented an HTML task board. When the user press on the "Save" button - then the JS code adds the user task into a container. Each task container has a "Remove" button, **But** when pressing on it - it deletes the first container child.

codes:

The "Save" button code:

```
 var mission =
 {     
    text: document.getElementById('textarea').value,
    date: document.getElementById('date').value,
    time: document.getElementById('time').value
 };

 const rows = document.getElementById('rows');
 const cell = document.createElement('div');
 const id = document.createAttribute('id');
 id.value = "div-cell";
 cell.setAttributeNode(id);
 cell.innerHTML = '<button id="remove-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right Align" onClick="removeButton()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><textarea></textarea><div><input><input></div>';
 rows.appendChild(cell);

 const [textarea, dateinput, timeinput] = cell.querySelectorAll('textarea, input'); 

 textarea.value = mission.text;
 dateinput.value = mission.date;
 timeinput.value = mission.time;
```

The "remove" button code:

```
function removeButton(){
  document.getElementById('rows').removeChild(document.getElementById('div-cell'));
}
```

I do understand that my code - looks for the first child and removes it. Can someone tell me how to 
remove the container which was pressed and not the first.

I thought about an array, but I've no idea how to implement it.

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Don't use a duplicate id, use a class instead.

Comment: OK, but if all 'div' elements will have the same class, it's not like they have the same id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the handler to get a reference to the clicked button (or its container) so that it can remove the container - the handler needs a parameter or it needs to check the event for that.

Another issue is that you're using an inline handler, which [have too many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). Attach the listener with Javascript instead, and inside the handler, you'll be able to reference the `cell` in the outer scope, and `.remove()` it:

```
button.onclick = () => cell.remove();
```

```js
var mission = {
  text: 'text',
  date: 'date',
  time: 'time'
};

const rows = document.getElementById('rows');
const cell = document.createElement('div');
cell.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">Remove</span></button><textarea></textarea><div><input><input></div>';
rows.appendChild(cell);

const [button, textarea, dateinput, timeinput] = cell.querySelectorAll('button, textarea, input');

button.onclick = () => cell.remove();
textarea.value = mission.text;
dateinput.value = mission.date;
timeinput.value = mission.time;
```

```html
<div id="rows"></div>
```

Note that there should be no more than one element with a particular ID in a document. In this case, there's no need for any id other than the `rows` container anyway.

Comment: Ginius! 

I got the idea! and this is how I've implemented:

cell.firstChild.addEventListener('click', function(){
rows.removeChild(cell);

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create the button with `createElement` so you can listen to the click event, and attach that to the container `cell` like so

```
// The cell which contains the button itself is being passed as a parameter
createRemoveButton = (cell) => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', _ => {
        document.getElementById('rows').removeChild(cell);
    });
    // Apply any styles needed...
    button.style.height = '20px';
    button.innerHTML = 'Remove';
    return button;
}
```

Then, when you are creating your `div-cell` element, just append the generated button with the callback on the `click` event.

```
// ...
const rows = document.getElementById('rows');
const cell = document.createElement('div');
const id = document.createAttribute('id');
id.value = 'div-cell';
cell.setAttributeNode(id);

const btn = createRemoveButton(cell);
cell.innerHTML = '<textarea></textarea><div><input><input></div>';
cell.appendChild(btn);

rows.appendChild(cell);
//...
```